# SQL Server - Difficulty with COUNT statement for multiple tables

Tags: sql-server, select, count

I'm having difficulty with the statement below.  I've tried writing it multiple ways, but receive different errors accordingly.  I'd like the result to be output to a single table with each count in a separate (but adjoining) column, like so...

```
 --------+--------+--------
| alias1 | alias2 | alias3 |
 --------+--------+--------
| count1 | count2 | count3 |
 --------+--------+--------
```

Method 1:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM AdventureWorks2012.HumanResources.Department AS Alias1
, (SELECT COUNT(*) 
    FROM AdventureWorks2012.HumanResources.Employee) AS Alias2
, (SELECT COUNT(*)  
    FROM AdventureWorks2012.HumanResources.EmployeeDepartmentHistory) AS Alias3
```

This returns an error on Alias2 (and Alias3) stating, "No column was specified for column 1 of 'Alias2'"

When I then try to rework it as follows:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM AdventureWorks2012.HumanResources.Department AS Alias1
, (SELECT COUNT(*) AS Alias2
    FROM AdventureWorks2012.HumanResources.Employee) 
, (SELECT COUNT(*) AS Alias3
    FROM AdventureWorks2012.HumanResources.EmployeeDepartmentHistory)
```

The error shifts to the ',' separating the SELECT statements with the error, "Incorrect syntax near ','. Expecting AS, ID, or QUOTED_ID."

What I'm attempting to do seems simple enough, but I'm coming up empty.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What version of SQL-Server is this? Note this natural join is deprecated in future versions (I think 2012 might still work,but not on outer joins (*=)

Comment: @clifton_h SQL Server has never supported natural join, do you mean the old-style, non-ANSI join syntax (FROM a,b) which leads to a cross join if you forget the where clause? If so, no, it has no been deprecated. Just not recommended.

Comment: Greg, why not just [pull the counts from `sys.partitions` instead of manually scanning all of the tables](http://sqlperformance.com/2014/10/t-sql-queries/bad-habits-count-the-hard-way)? Or is this fictitious query against AdventureWorks tables not truly describing your actual problem?

Comment: @Aaron.Bertrand then what do you call this query?  I rechecked my assumed knowledge, and I see i confused the two terms again. They are similar in form, true enough. Guess I learnt something. :)

Comment: @clifton_h I'm using ver 2014.

Comment: @Aaron.Bertrand It describes the nature of the problem, but I'm working with an entirely different DB.  Thanks for the suggestion,though.

Comment: @TheyCallMeGreg The same principles apply - if you are really looking for a count of all rows from a bunch of tables, it's much more efficient to get this information from the DMVs and catalog views instead of performing expensive COUNT(*) from every table. [This is described in the link I posted](http://sqlperformance.com/2014/10/t-sql-queries/bad-habits-count-the-hard-way).

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT 
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM AdventureWorks2012.HumanResources.Department)  AS Alias1, 
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM AdventureWorks2012.HumanResources.Employee) AS Alias2, 
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM AdventureWorks2012.HumanResources.EmployeeDepartmentHistory) AS Alias3
```

Comment: This appears to work exactly as desired.  Thank you very much, Anton!

Answer (score 0):

One way to get the result you want would be to use each statement as a derived table:

```
SELECT * FROM 
(SELECT COUNT(*) AS Alias1 FROM AdventureWorks2012.HumanResources.Department) AS a1 , 
(SELECT COUNT(*) AS Alias2 FROM AdventureWorks2012.HumanResources.Employee) AS a2, 
(SELECT COUNT(*) AS Alias3 FROM AdventureWorks2012.HumanResources.EmployeeDepartmentHistory) AS a3
```

(Or you could use the statements as subqueries as shown in another answer)